# Get html object from nodename and nodeindex

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am trying to get the position of an html element by nodeName and nodeIndex.  I currently use this by passing the nodename and index from the database however...(see below)

```
    $thing = $("BUTTON").eq(1);
    thisLeft = $thing.offset().left;
    thisTop = $thing.offset().top;
    x_left = thisLeft + x_coord
    y_top = thisTop + y_coord
```

I would like to use the following function which works onclick when I pass the object because of its accuracy to get the position even if its in parent elements.  Is it possible to pass in the nodename and nodeindex (which I have in a database) like my example of $("BUTTON").eq(1) to return the accurate x and y from the following function...

```
function findPos(obj) {
var curleft = 0, curtop = 0;
if (obj.offsetParent) {
    do {
        curleft += obj.offsetLeft;
        curtop += obj.offsetTop;
    } while (obj = obj.offsetParent);
    return { x: curleft, y: curtop };
}
return undefined;
 }
```

This function from the click handler outputs the correct x and y...

```
var pos = findPos(e);
        var x = e.pageX - pos.x;
        var y = e.pageY - pos.y;
        var coordinateDisplay = "x=" + x + ", y=" + y;
        console.log(coordinateDisplay);
```

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetParent#Compatibility

Comment: thanks guest271314, that is what findPos is doing, just need to see if I can integrate offsetParent.

Comment: Yes, posted link for note concerning `webkit` ; if  `css` `display:none` , `position:fixed` set at element; element, element ancestors possibly returning `null`

Answer (score 1):

Html 5 allows a data tag attribute which you can read about with JQuery [here](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/).

When you generate the nodes from your database you can do something like

```
<div class="node" data-nodeName="ImANode" data-nodeIndex="0" ></div>
```

Then you can select each one with

```
$("div[data-nodeName='ImANode'][data-nodeIndex='0']")
```